# Google Calendar push notifications callback troubleshooting

Tags: c#, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I've implemented a c# app which creates calendar events using the calendar API.

In order to keep the calendar in sync with our local db I've created a watch on the calendar. The following code does this and, as far as I can see, a watch is created.

```
Channel watchChannel = new Channel()
{
    Id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_CALENDAR_WATCH_NAME"],
    Type = "web_hook",
    Address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_CALENDAR_SYNC_TRIGGER_CALLBACK_URL"],
    Expiration = (unixTimestamp + NINETY_DAYS_IN_SECONDS) * 1000 //milliseconds
};

try
{
    logger.Debug("Creating calendar watch with the name " +
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GOOGLE_CALENDAR_WATCH_NAME"] + " for calendar with id " + remoteCalendarId);
    Channel returnChannel = service.Events.Watch(watchChannel, remoteCalendarId).Execute();
```

My problem is that the callback URL isn't getting called (i have confirmed ownership of the domain and authenticated it for the user, that shouldn't be the issue).

- How do I debug this? Is there anywhere I can look at the attempts google is
  making to call the callback URL?
- I say that as far as I can see everything is created ok, but maybe I'm wrong, which property in the
  returnChannel should I be looking at?
- Is there any way to list all created watches/channels for a particular calendar? If so, which API is that exposed through?

**04.04 - A bit more information:**

These are the parameters set on the outgoing call (watchChannel) and return-object (returnChannel).

**watchChannel**

- Address  "https://a.domain.com/api/schedule/syncDbAndSchedule"
- ETag = null
- Expiration = 1491309746000
- Id =     "my_id_watch_dev"
- Kind  =  null
- Params__  = null
- Payload =    null
- ResourceId =     null
- ResourceUri =    null
- Token      = null
- Type  =  "web_hook"

**returnChannel**

- Address =    null
- ETag =   null
- Expiration =     1491309746000
- Id =     "my_id_watch_dev"
- Kind =   "api#channel"
- Params__ =   null
- Payload =    null
- ResourceId =     "t6uxfXzXXXXXXXXXXsC9ZEqMdzU"
- ResourceUri =    "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/a.domain.com_nsqpp2XXXXXX93olf0ul40sphg@group.calendar.google.com/events?maxResults=250&alt=json"
- Token =  null
- Type =   null

Looking at it again I've got a few more questions:

- Can I be sure the above returned a HTTP-200 response? The client-libs seem to abstract away the actual request/response and I can't find any trace of it in the objects I'm looking at. As the 4xx responses I've gotten have been transformed into exceptions that's what I'd expect for any non-200 response but can I be sure of that?
- Is there really no way to track the attempts google is making whilst calling the callback URL? Since there seems to be no way to get a hold of a created watch it kind of surprises me there is no GUI where I can track this. Makes hunting for errors really hard.

**Code to authenticate**

I use the following code to authenticate the system user and then make it act in the guise of a 'normal' non-system account (since a pure system-account seemed a tricky way to go if you actually wanted to look at the calendar too).

```
ServiceAccountCredential credential = 
    GoogleCredential.FromJson(GOOGLE_SYSTEM_USER_AUTH_INFORMATION)
        .CreateScoped(Scopes)
        .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;

var userField =
    typeof(ServiceAccountCredential).GetField("user", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
userField?.SetValue(credential, GOOGLE_CALENDAR_USERNAME); //Act in the guise of the normal user GOOGLE_CALENDAR_USERNAME


service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});
```

on a whim I visited the ResourceURI returned. It gives me

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Is

- this the status for the watch? If so, why didn't I get a 403 whilst    creating it?
- Am I really Unautenticated or is it just that my request through a browser is?

Comment: What changes have you tried making to the calendar events? What is the value of `unixTimestamp`? (It would help if you'd provide a [mcve].) I can't see any way of listing watches... as well as confirming ownership, have you added the domain to the list for your project, as per https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push#registering?

Comment: I updated my question with a bit more information. To answer your questions. Unixtimestamp - see above. Domain is added to the list for the project (this is what I meant by having confirmed ownership, although that was a bit imprecise). There isn't really a way for me to provide you with a verifiable example since that would mean me having to publish the keys we use.

Comment: Thanks - will take a look, and raise it internally if I can't figure it out :(

Comment: Wow, talk about quick response. Please tell me if I can supply you with any information which will help you. As you can see I've purposely X-ed out information which would identify the watch uniquely. I should also mention the call is  being made through a service-account with domain-wide permissions. And using the same account I was able to get this up and running previously albeit with slightly different parameters in a PoC (I've tried running the PoC which workd previously again and now it doesn't so I'm running into so me kind of call-limitation it would seem).

Comment: That's useful information in itself. Either there's a limitation, or possibly something's been broken. I doubt that I'll be able to work it out directly, but I'll make sure someone does :)

Comment: Added the actual code I use since it's  system user but I act in the guise of a 'normal' user. Thought that could be relevant input.

Comment: Yes, it might well be. I wouldn't assume that you can just do that and still end up with a valid credential. I suggest you try using a `UserCredential` instead - at least so we can rule this out as the cause of the problem.

Comment: i added a bit of information regarding what happens when I visit the resourceURI. Regarding the UserCredential: How do I create one through a system user account, do you have any example code? I don't really want to log in as the user I'm acting in the guise of, that messes with the security-structure I want (and which I should be able to create according to the docs).

Comment: BTW, using the exact same setup (same code) inserting, deleting and updating events in a calendar work flawlessly (i.e. a system-user acting in the guise of a normal user).

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should necessarily do this as the normal user in your real code - the point is to reduce the code required to reproduce the problem to as "normal" code as possible.

Comment: Slight aside: rather than messing around with reflection, I'd strongly recommend that you create a new `ServiceAccountCredential` from the existing one by creating a `ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer` from the existing properties, setting the `User` property, and then calling the `ServiceAccountCredential` constructor that takes the initializer. If that description isn't enough, I suggest you ask a new question for that part and I'll answer it :)

Comment: I suspect the resource URI error you're getting is indeed due to a lack of authentication due to using a browser. You may want to try fetching it from code with the HttpClient initialized with the service account credential.

Comment: Tried the resourceURI with the authenticated HttpClient, it gave me back a  list of events in the calendar. Don't think it was a complete list though (will check).

Comment: If you have an example of the creation of a `ServiceAccountCredential` for a user from the properties of a system one then I'd appreciate it. *I tried but didn't succeed. Also, any other threads you see that I can pursue? I'm a bit stuck ATM since the part I'm interested in is on servers I don't control and AFAIK can't get any output from.

Comment: Please ask a new question (and link to it here) about the ServiceAccountCredential part, and I'll add an answer. I'm asking internally about the main problem though.

Comment: As per @JonSkeet request, broke out the ServiceAccountCredential part to a freestanding question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256237/creating-a-serviceaccountcredential-for-a-user-from-a-systems-account

Comment: As you seem to be in direct communication with the correct people, my suggestion for a more user-friendly, hands-off (from your perspective) approach: Create an API through which I can get all the created watches on a particular element and allow me to look at it's status and in the case of a callback also allow me to look at the last/n-latest attempts to perform a callback request. It kind of surprises me that this isn't available already, Google APIs tend to be well thought through and complete. This doesn't seem to be (or I'm missing something essential)

Comment: I've included the diagnostics aspect in the internal issue report - along with a link to this question.

Comment: Suggestion from the team: try creating the channel from the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/) - if you do that, does that make your endpoint get hit? If so, it might be an auth issue.

Comment: I am supposed to create it using https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.watch right? I can't seem to make sense of which parameters to fill in in order to get the desired effect, only channelId is mandatory. What is the parameter-equivalent of the settings i set using the Channel object in the dot-net libs? I'm assuming they abstract away some of the complexities of the interface. My challenge using the raw interface is that I don't know what a proper request looks like or where to  put them (request body as payload?)

Comment: Hmm. It may indeed be what goes in the channel body. You could look at what the .NET client library does though - as of the 1.24.x release, you can set request logging up fairly easily.

Comment: I'll answer that one myself, the available parameters turn up in the request body. I managed to fire off a request using the same login that owns the servicelogin. I have verified that the domain I want the callback from is in the list (I had to add it again strangely enough). When I make calls logged in as this user I get:     "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: If I look at the header in the response I can also see: www-authenticate:  Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token which I don't know what means.

Comment: Request logging could help, any guides/examples out there?

Comment: Not offhand - I'll see what I can do next week. (I'm now on vacation until Tuesday.) I suggest you add that information into the question though. (I'm not sure what you mean by "When I make calls logged in as this user" - calls to what, exactly?)

Comment: I'm still hoping to add some docs around request/response logging, but for the moment I think it would be best to file a bug directly with the calendar team - this kind of trouble-shooting isn't really what SO was designed for. (I think it was fine to *ask* here first, it's just it turns out that the problem isn't as easily tractable as it might be.) I suggest you delete this question - at least for now; you could undelete it with an answer once we know what's going on - and file a bug in https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/support ("Report a new bug").

Comment: Reported as an issue. My issue has been marked as a dupe (which I guess is a good thing since that should mean i'm not the only one having problems). My new problem is that I'm not allowed to look at the details of the issue it's marked as a dupe of and this have no way of seeing the current status. Is there any way around that? (I know I'm off topic here but my comments in my original issue have gone unnoticed).

Comment: I'll ask internally, but then I would suggest deleting this SO question.

Comment: What are my options as far as getting the current status on this goes? Since it's linked to another issue I'm not allowed to look at I don't see how I'll know when/if something happens. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36934141 (the issue I'm not allowed to look at)

Comment: I'll ask internally about getting access for you on that bug... I don't know much about that side of things, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The callback url must be https (certificate) otherwise it will not be called!