# Create Google Calendar Event With Credentials To Impersonate User with Google Calendar API Library .NET 7 C#

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, blazor, google-calendar-api

In .NET 7, without specifying a User in the

```
ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(original.Id)
```

block, my calendar event can be created with no errors. But if I specify a user as shown below, I get this error:

> Error: unauthorized_client,
> Description: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.

My service account has domain-wide delegation, allowed scope of
calendar via OAuth2, and I have specifically granted the SA access to the user's calendar (when I try on accounts that have not specifically granted access, I can't create a calendar entry at all).

How do I get appropriate credentials for the service account to impersonate the end user within my domain?

Credit for getting this far to [creating-a-serviceaccountcredential-for-a-user-from-a-systems-account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256237/creating-a-serviceaccountcredential-for-a-user-from-a-systems-account)

Previous answers don't seem to be working on latest release.

In my API code, which calls the authentication service then creates the event:

```
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.CalendarService CS = await SA.AuthenticateServiceAccountSO();

var result = CS.Events.Insert((Event)newEvent, clientemail).Execute();
```

In Service AuthenticateServiceAccountSO():

```
public async Task<CalendarService> AuthenticateServiceAccountSO()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    string? serviceAccountCredentialFilePath = _config.GetValue<string>("ServiceAccountFilePath");
    string? ClientEmail = _config.GetValue<string>("TestingUserAccountEmail");
    
    string[] scopes = new string[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar };
    
    ServiceAccountCredential original = (ServiceAccountCredential)GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath).UnderlyingCredential;
    
    var initializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(original.Id)
                          {
                              User = ClientEmail,
                              Key = original.Key,
                              Scopes = scopes
                          };
    
    var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);
    
    CalendarService service = new(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Calendar_Appointment event Using Service Account Authentication"
                });
    
    return service;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently copying relatively little of the service account credential - in particular, there's no `KeyId`. But you can do it all much more simply anyway:

```cs
var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath)
    .CreateScoped(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar)
    .CreateWithUser(ClientEmail);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. This throws same errors for calendars w/explicit "make changes and manage events" as for calendars w/no perms for SA (progress!).
 ```           var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(serviceAcctCredPath)
                  .CreateScoped(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);
                  .CreateWithUser(ClientEmail);

            CalendarService service = new(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "appname"
            });``` -Ugh - can't format code in comment :(

Comment: @user13814551: At that point I'm afraid I can't help you - domain-wide delegation is outside my knowledge domain, mostly... but this is definitely the preferred way of creating a delegating credential now. (I'll update my answer from 2017...)

Comment: make sure that ClientEmail is an email of a user on your google workspace domain.  this is not the service account email addres

Comment: Got it! I had misunderstood the concept of the OAuth scopes, and thought I need to create separate OAuth permissions and grant them to the service account... too much googling apparently.  This link has a good description of the process: https://docs.metaspike.com/article/39-using-delegation-with-g-suite